Are these colored sets closed under multiplication?
A set is called closed under multiplication if the product of any two (not necessarily distinct) elements of the set is always a member of the set. For example, the integers are closed under multiplication.
Suppose that every real number is colored either green or blue such that the product of any three (not necessarily distinct) green numbers is a green number and the product of any three (not necessarily distinct) blue numbers is a blue number. Let G be the set of green numbers and B be the set of blue numbers.
Assume that you know nothing about the coloring other than it satisfies the above conditions.

Question 1:  Is it necessarily true that at least one of the sets is closed under multiplication?

Question 2: Is it necessarily true that both sets are closed under multiplication?

Question 3: Is it possible that both sets are closed under multiplication?


Attribution:  Mostly momath.org, partly me

Does your definition of closedness apply to two identical numbers?

Yes.  For example consider the 2-element set S={$a,b$}.  Set S is closed under multiplication if and only if $a^2$, $ab$ and $b^2$ are all elements of S.  I have updated my question.


Question 1: Is it necessarily true that at least one of the sets is closed under multiplication?


 Yes. Otherwise, you'd have $g_1g_2=b_3$ and $b_1b_2=g_3$ for some greens $g_i$ and some blues $b_i$. But then $g_1g_2g_3=b_1b_2b_3$, a contradiction.


Question 2: Is it necessarily true that both sets are closed under multiplication?


 No. The greens can be the negatives, which are not closed under multiplication.


Question 3: Is it possible that both sets are closed under multiplication?


 Yes. The set of blues can be $\lbrace0\rbrace$.


For Question 3, do you think it is possible that both sets are infinite AND closed under multiplication?

@Will.Octagon.Gibson  Take the set of real numbers with magnitude less than 1, and the other set is its complement (in the reals), then both sets are closed under multiplication.  Modulo little variations as to whether 0 and/or 1 are in the first set vs in the second, for a total of 4 variants on the same idea, I'd even think that is the only possible solution as for partitioning the real numbers in two infinite sets: though I cannot think of a proof...

@JulioDiEgidio That’s cool!

I'm not following the explanation for (1): you're demonstrating with a product of 2 elements, but we only know property for a product of 3 elements, so I'm not sure of your precondition. Would you mind explaining in a little more details?

@MatthieuM.: If neither set is closed under multiplication (ie assume it's not true that at least one is closed), then there must be elements that satisfy $g_1g_2=b_3$ and vice versa because that's what the definition of not being closed means. That doesn't immediately help, because as you say that's a 2-product and we only have a rule for a 3-product - but to be able to apply that rule, just multiply the two equations together (making sure all the $g$s and all the $b$s are on the same side).

@MatthieuM.: As an alternative proof: observe that the number 1 must be either green or blue. Assuming it's blue: for any $b_2$, $b_3$, it's true that $1 \times b_2 \times b_3$ is blue (since that's a 3-product). But that's just $b_2b_3$ - so in this case the blues are closed under multiplication. If instead 1 is green, by a similar argument the greens must be closed in that case. So whichever colour includes 1 is closed under multiplication.

@psmears: Rereading the problem, I notice my understanding was flawed. There's talk about product of 2 numbers (closed under multiplication) and product of 3 numbers ($g_1g_2g_3$ is green & $b_1b_2b_3$ is blue), and I muddled the both of them, thinking that "closed under multiplication" referred to product of 3 numbers. My mistake.

@MatthieuM.: Fair enough - I certainly had to read the question a few times before I fully understood what was going on :-)

Problem statement and headline result
This is a partial answer to the tougher question asked in comments on msh210's answer:
(3bis) How can the real numbers be partitioned in two sets that are both closed under multiplication and infinite?
Per Julio Di Egidio (comment on msh210's answer):

Take the set of real numbers with magnitude less than 1, and the other set is its complement (in the reals), then both sets are closed under multiplication. Modulo little variations as to whether 0 and/or 1 are in the first set vs in the second, for a total of 4 variants on the same idea, I'd even think that is the only possible solution as for partitioning the real numbers in two infinite sets: though I cannot think of a proof...

I prove in the following that for any substantially different solution, at least one of the sets is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (that is: for any real $x$, at any tolerance $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element of the set within distance $\epsilon$ of $x$). This does not disprove the existence of such solutions, but it puts considerable constraints upon them; at the very least it hints that one should not be able to find them "by hand".
Let us call $A$ and $B$ the sets that form such a partition (the "green" and "blue" sets in the original). (added per psmears' comment)
Proof
Lemma 1: $A$ and $B$ are stable by the operation "take the opposite".
Proof: assume without loss of generality that $-1\in A$. Assume there exist $r\in A$ such that $-r\in B$. Then $(-1)\times r$ is not in $A$, which is contradictory. Hence no such $r$ (or $-r$) exists, hence $A$ (or $B$) is stable by the operation "take the opposite".
This allows us to consider only non-negative numbers.
Lemma 2: let $\alpha>0$ be an irrational positive number. Let $x>0$ be a non-negative real number. Then, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $m,n$ integers such that $0<\left(n - m\alpha\right) <\epsilon$.
Proof: This is a weak version of Dirichlet's approximation theorem. The only difficulty is that we want $n - m\alpha$ to be non-negative.
Define $x_k,-n_k$ as the decimal and integer parts of $-k\alpha$ (i.e., $-k\alpha=-n_k+x_k$ with $n_k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $0 \leq x_k < 1$). Because $\alpha$ is irrational, the set ${x_k}$ is dense in $[0,1($ (well-known result - see for instance this question on math.se). In particular, there exists $k$ such that $x_k<\epsilon$. Then, $m=k, n=n_k$ satisfy the desired condition.
Definition: Let $0<p<1<q$. We say $p$ and $q$ are "co-exponential" if $log_q(p)\in \mathbb{Q}$ (or, equivalently by definition of the logarithm, if $\exists r\in Q, p^r=q$).
Lemma 3: assume there exists $0<p<1<q$ with $p,q\in A$ not co-exponential. Then $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.
Proof:
First, notice that since $p,q\in A$, then $p^m q^n\in A$ for any integers $m,n$.
Define $\alpha := log_q(p)$, which is irrational by hypothesis. Then $p^m q^n = q^{n - m\alpha}$.
Let $x>0$; we want to find $m,n$ such that $p^m q^n$ is "close to" $x$. That is equivalent to finding $m,n$ such that $n - m\alpha$ is "close to" $log_q(x)$. (A rigorous proof requires a bit more complexity, but it works because the $log_q$ function is continuously differentiable on any non-negative real.) Define $f(m,n):=n - m\alpha$.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be our tolerance. From lemma 2, we can find $m',n'$ such that $0<f(m',n')<\epsilon$. Define k as the quotient of the Euclidean division of $log_q(x)$ by $f(m',n')$. Then $k f(m',n') = f(km',kn') \leq log_q(x) < (k+1) f(m',n') < f(km',kn') + \epsilon$. Therefore $m=km',n=kn'$ satisfies the condition.
Theorem: Either $]0,1[\subset A$ and $]1,\infty[\subset B$, or $]0,1[\subset B$ and $]1,\infty[\subset A$, or at least one of $A$ and $B$ is dense is $\mathbb{R}$.
First, we consider the edge cases, and show they come down either to Julio Di Egidio's solution or a trivial solution (where either set is finite):

if $A\cap ]0,1[$ is empty, then

$]0,1[\subset B$
Furthermore

if $B\cap ]1,\infty[$ is empty, then $]1,\infty[\subset A$ (case 2 of the theorem).
Otherwise, let $q\in B\cap ]1,\infty[$. For any $x>0$, there exists $N$ such that $q^N>x$; then, $q^N$ is in $B$ and $x/q^N$ is in $]0,1[$ hence also in $B$, thus $x$ is in $B$. Therefore $]1,\infty[\subset B$. Combined with the previous point, $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (case 3 of the theorem).




if $B\cap ]0,1[$ is empty, the same reasoning as above applies, reversing the roles of $A$ and $B$ (yielding cases 1 and 3 respectively).

Having dealt with the edge cases, let us assume there exists $p_A\in A$ with $0<p_A<1$ and $p_B\in B$ with $0<p_B<1$.
Consider the set $S_p:=\{p^r, r\in \mathbb{Q}\}$. That set is countable (because rationals are countable). As a consequence, $S_{p_A}\cup S_{p_B}$ is countable. Since $]1,\infty[$ is uncountable, it contains elements that are not in $S_{p_A}\cup S_{p_B}$. Let $q$ be one such element. Then neither $p_A$ and $q$ nor $p_B$ and $q$ are co-exponential.
If $q\in A$, then by lemma 3 applied to $p_A,q$, $A$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise, $q\in B$, and by the same lemma applied to $p_B,q$, $B$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

There are a lot of these other solutions! First, here is a recipe to colour $\mathbb{R}$ so that the sets are closed under addition: Suppose we pick any $\mathbb{Q}$-basis of $\mathbb{R}$, call it $S$. For each element $r \in S$, we can then make the binary choice on colouring $r$ blue and $-r$ green or vice versa. Having done all these choices, we can extend the colouring to all positive rational linear combinations (and colour 0 any which way.) This clearly gives a partition into infinite sets closed under addition. This colouring can then be made multiplicative by applying  ...

... the exponential function and extending to negatives symmetrically. Note that the "nice" solutions correspond to the choice of picking the colours among $r$ and $-r$ (in the first comment) according to the sign. I haven't thought this through, but I suspect that the existence of these other exotic colourings could well be independent of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

What are $A$ and $B$? They're not defined anywhere in the question or here (I assume they're any "blue" and "green" sets?). I'm assuming "take the opposite" means "negate"?

@TimSeifert Nicely done. Now to prove those are the only solutions... (Also, why did I not think to work with additive stability after lemma 1? It’s much simpler to reason this way!)

Oh hang on, my first idea doesn't work at all! These subsets are far from forming a partition :/ But here is an idea that does work and gives just as many colourings: Fix any linear surjection $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Q}$. Then the preimages $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Q}{<0})$ and $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Q}{\geq 0})$ do form a partition and are closed under addition. The rest can be done the same way. Here, it is actually clear that the usual coloring is not of this form, since for every colouring of this type, one subset contains an infinite-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space ...


 If $1$ is blue, the blue set is closed, so Q1 is true.  So if no blue numbers are infinite, their absolute values can't exceed $1$ because otherwise they can all grow farther and farther from 0 indefinitely. If we paint all the numbers from $-1$ to $1$ blue and the rest green, then both sets will be closed, making Q3 true.  There are a few simple ways to create closed (blue) sets:  - All consist of the numbers $x, x^2, x^3,...$: Then three numbers from the other green set can give a product equal to a member of the closed set and create a contradiction.  - Numbers from $0$ to $1$: Then two negative numbers over $-1$ and a positive one above $1$ can yield a blue product, also leading to a contradiction.  - Numbers from $-1$ to $1$: Makes both sets closed.  - All non-negative numbers: Makes only the blue set closed.  Only the last option works for Q2.

Additional observation/stuff that can be useful to expand the answer:

 Take all powers of a positive number. Any positive number can be written as a power of it, which turns closedness under multiplication into closedness of exponents under addition.  If $x$ is green, then so is $\sqrt(x)$, because the blue set is closed. Then it goes like $x^{1/2^n}$. By extension, $(x^{1/2^n})^{3+2k}$ numbers are all green. $(x^{1/2^n})^2$ also works, so all that remains is $(x^{1/2^n})^{6k}$, but if $(x^{1/2^n})^{4k}*(x^{1/2^n})^{k}*(x^{1/2^n})^{k}$ work, so do these. That is, all integer-exponent powers of $x^{1/2^n}$ are green.  $b^2=b$  $b^3=b$  $g^3=g$  $b^{1/3}=b$  $g^{1/3}=g$  $g^{1/2}=-g^{1/2}=g$


Not sure what makes my answer wrong here. Genuinely confused.

It's not wrong, but it's not good either. 1) You don't add anything that other answers did not add before. 2) You don't explain very well your reasonning  3) The sentences  are confusing and hard to follow (like the last paragraph of the first spoiler block: "a few simple ways", but you start with a contradiction ?!? What are you trying to show there ?).  Did not downvote, just telling why I think this answer is not well received

1- I see plenty of answers that get upvoted despite not adding anything, so it's annoying that these double standards come my way. 2 & 3- English isn't my first language, and not everyone is equally talented with languages. And what do you mean by "hard to follow" anyway? 90% of y'all are smarter than me, so it's not like anyone will have a problem understanding simpler ideas than theirs.

The top answer didn't delve into the reasoning either. Why the heck should it ONLY apply to me? People are just looking for excuses to downvote me unless my answer is completely perfect and airtight.

Your answer currently only has 1 vote which happens to be a downvote.  A single vote, either upvote or downvote, doesn’t really mean very much.

Maybe I'm overreacting, but even if my answer is considered "useless", it's not harmful or misleading, so I don't get the point of treating a harmless answer as detrimental and worth downvoting. The only reason might be that people think I'm a plagiarist who steals already created answers to farm points. And that's a serious accusation you can't throw around willy-nilly.

If you think I'm a plagiarist, stop playing games. Just report me and get rid of me already.

You are overreacting. The pointers I gave you are not gospel, just my interpretation. I cannot know why the single downvoter did so, I can only guess. Don't take those as personnal attacks, I was just trying to help you identify possible reasons why you received a downvote.

Sorry, I didn't mean to attack you, I was just trying to understand the motives of the one(s) who downvoted me in particular (but not others for the same reasons you stated). It happens quite a few times to me even if my answer is technically correct and not misleading, so they must have thought I was guilty of some sort of an offense (likely plagiarism) to see it fit to downvote my answer. I hope I'm making sense; English isn't my first language.

There's a pattern going on: I like a question, but I'm not smart enough to solve it quickly, so some 200 IQ super-genius makes all his points that I can't add to even if I do manage to eventually come up with a solution, then I end up getting downvoted because everyone assumes I plagiarized his solution. It's so frustrating.

There is no pattern going on : your last answer with negative score before this one was in 2022. And even if a pattern was found, plagia should result in a flag, not a downvote. Downvote are for "not usefull" answer (hover the downvote button)

@AloisChristen In September 2023, one of my answers on this site was plagiarized by another user on this site. The post that plagiarized my answer got 11 downvotes.  I flagged that post and it got deleted.

@AloisChristen The Puzzling Help Center article at https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing begins by stating, Plagiarism - posting the work of others with no indication that it is not your own - is frowned on by our community, and may result in your content being downvoted or deleted.
